# Select option with minimum value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have JSON:

```
[{name:'Mary', phone:'555-9876', age:19, date:'2011-06-12T00:00:00.000Z'},
{name:'John', phone:'555-1212', age:10, date:'2011-06-11T00:00:00.000Z'},
{name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321', age:21, date:'2011-07-13T00:00:00.000Z'},
{name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678', age:35, date:'2011-05-14T00:00:00.000Z'},
{name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765', age:29, date:'2011-06-15T00:00:00.000Z'}]
```

I should create the `<select>` and select the name with minimum age. In my case - John.

My controller:

```
function Projects ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.rootEntry = [];
    $http.get('/api/...').success(function(root) {
        $scope.rootEntry = root;
        $scope.selectedRoot = $scope.rootEntry[0].name;
    });
}
```

And HTML:

```
<select ng-options="root.age as root.name for root in rootEntry ng-model="selectedRoot">
</select>
```

I can select first item - `$scope.selectedRoot = $scope.rootEntry[0].name;`

How can I select minimum age?

Comment: It is fairly trivial to loop through your data and keep track of the lowest `age` value. Are you having trouble writing that code?

Comment: @AndrewArnold, no, it's easy.  I thought Angular has something special for this.

Comment: Angular does, I fiddled it here - http://jsfiddle.net/devitate/LKeQz/
basically you can use/provide filters by [filter]Filter, so orderByFilter will sort your array and max would just be '-age' etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to take this, you can start with $filter and orderBy
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy
which should give you a list sorted by age on your ngRepeat or $filterprovider, then just grab the first element.

fiddled it out here - http://jsfiddle.net/devitate/LKeQz/

**Without any testing** 
The fancy way would look something like this - *don't trust this code though*.

```
var min = Math.min.apply(null,
   Object.keys($scope.rootEntry).map(function(e) {
        return $scope.rootEntry[e]['age'];
   })
);
```

Or, an easier to understand way, for me at least, would just be a loop and it would go something like -

```
 var ages = [];
 angular.forEach( $scope.rootEntry , function(value, key) {
   ages.push(value.age);
 });
 return Math.min(ages);
```

But you should probably just skip ahead to using underscore js -

```
_.min($scope.rootEntry, function(e){ return e.age; });
```

Answer (score 1):

In your success handler, iterate through `$scope.rootEntry` to find the item with the smallest age and assign that value to `$scope.selectedRoot`.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. I thought Angular has something special for this.